# How can I set a filter on send port that will not process the message if handled by an earlier send port in my orchestration?

Tags: c#, sql-server, biztalk

I have an orchestration that creates a new message if a condition is met, sends new the message out to the send port, then sends the original message to a discard folder. This works ok. If the condition is not met, it just recycles the message and sends it back out. Right now it is hitting the discard folder, no matter what filter I set up. Here is the orchestration. Anyone know how I can accomplish this. The discard folder can get really full very quickly. [image]

All my filtering and port information is set up on the Biztalk Administration server. This is what I need to achieve. A message comes in. It gets processed against the database. The database request returns an empty set. In this scenario I want to pause the orchestration, then send the message out to a send folder. It has a process to move the message to the receive folder, and the message gets processed again. If the database returns data, the data is processed, then a new message is created with new parameters then sent to the send folder and moved to the receive folder.

The original message gets sent to a discard folder. The new message with new parameters gets processed again, each time updating parameters and getting run again, until it returns no data. It is then reset in a new message and the process starts all over.

There are different messages of the same type. Each call to the database, must have a corresponding message.

Comment: All my filtering and port information is set up on the Biztalk Administration server.  This is what I need to achieve. A message comes in. It gets processed against the database. The database request returns an empty set. In this scenario I want to pause the orchestration, then send the message out to a send folder. It has a process to move the message to the receive folder, and the message gets processed again. If the database returns data, the data is processed, then a new message is created with new parameters then sent to the send folder and moved to the receive folder.

Comment: The original message gets sent to a discard folder. The new message with new parameters gets processed again, each time updating parameters and getting run again, until it returns no data.  It is then reset in a new message and the process starts all over.

Comment: Yes, but there are different messages of the same type.  Each call to the database, must have a corresponding message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, set change the Operation Name and the logical send port from Operation_1 to something meaningful and Unique.

On the Send Port, add the filter `BTS.Operation = <operation name>`

Comment: Thanks. Once I changed the send port operation names and set up the filters using BTS.Operation = <operation name> all messages went where they were designated to go.  Consider this Answered.